# Анимация изменения цвета фона

Tags: python, pyqt5, анимация, qpropertyanimation, qcolor

Хочу реализовать функцию вспышки. 
Цвет фона должен меняться на новый, а затем плавно возвращаться обратно.

Я сделал так:

```py
import sys
from copy import copy, deepcopy
from classes.statistics import Statistics
from IPython.external.qt_for_kernel import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QBrush
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, Qt


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, width=900, height=900, font_size=20, input_size=(25, 30), background_color=[60, 170, 255],
                 red=[255, 0, 0], green=[0, 255, 0]):
        super().__init__()

        self.width, self.height = width, height
        self.resize(width, height)

        self.background_color = background_color
        self.red = red
        self.green = green

        self.setupUi()

    def flash(self, start_color, time=5000, step=100):
        steps = [(self.background_color[i] - start_color[i]) / time * step for i in range(3)]
        print('steps =', steps)
        current_color = copy(start_color)

        for i in range(0, time, step):
            QTimer.singleShot(i, lambda: self.set_color(copy(current_color)))
            print(f'{i} ms before {current_color}')
            for i in range(3):
                current_color[i] += steps[i]

    def red_flash(self, time=5000, step=100):
        self.flash(self.red, time=time, step=step)

    def green_flash(self, time=5000, step=100):
        self.flash(self.green, time=time, step=step)

    def set_color(self, color):
        print('setting color', color)
        self.palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Background, QColor(*color))
        self.setPalette(self.palette)
        self.show()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        self.palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Background, QColor("#99ccff"))
        self.setPalette(self.palette)

        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    w.red_flash()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Если посмотреть вывод программы:

```
0 ms before [255, 0, 0]
100 ms before [190.0, 56.666666666666664, 85.0]
200 ms before [125.0, 113.33333333333333, 170.0]
setting color [60.0, 170.0, 255.0]
setting color [60.0, 170.0, 255.0]
setting color [60.0, 170.0, 255.0]
```

то видно, что несколько раз вызывается метод`set_color()` с разными цветами. 
Однако когда функция начинает выполняться, то каждый раз она использует один и тот-же цвет.

В чем может быть проблема?

Может я выбрал неправильный метод для реализации задумки и есть другой более правильный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс `QPropertyAnimation` анимирует свойства Qt.

Больше... https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpropertyanimation.html

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *

        
class Label(QLabel): 
    def __init__(self, text=None, parent=None):
        super(Label, self).__init__(text, parent)
        self._color = QColor()

    def get_color(self):
        return self._color

    def set_color(self, col):
        self._color = col
        self.setStyleSheet(
            'background-color: rgb({}, {}, {})'.format(col.red(), col.green(), col.blue())
        )
        
    color = pyqtProperty(QColor, fget=get_color, fset=set_color)


class Demo(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget(self)          
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        
        self.label = Label('Color', self)
        
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.label, b'color')
        self.animation.setDuration(5000)
        self.animation.setStartValue(QColor(255, 50, 50))
        self.animation.setEndValue(QColor(0, 255, 255))
        self.animation.setLoopCount(-1)
        self.animation.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Demo()
    w.resize(600, 600)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]